# Object creation from list <Class>

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to create a new instance of a object which is holding a list object of another class.

```
public Class A
{
    int a { get; set; };

    List<B> b  { get; set; }

}




public Class B
{
    int c { get; set; };
}



public Class Test
{
    A a= new A();
    a.b= ? how to initiate this

    a.b.c=some value;
```

}

I am not getting this value c here.how to get This value.

Comment: With such declaration you cannot even READ `b` property. I'd do it in `A` constructor (`b = new List<B>();`). From "outside" you have to declare that properties as `public` and write (for example): `a.b = new List<C>();`. Your last line is wrong because it's a list, you can ADD an object to the list with `a.b.Add(new B { c = 123 });`. I'd suggest to start with a simple C# tutorial...

Comment: You'll have to add a constructor to Class A that instantiates an instance of the List<B> class and assigns it to b.

Comment: another problem is that you doesn't use acess modifiers next to properties

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
public Class A
{
    public int a { get; set; };

    public List<B> b  { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        b = new List<B>();
    }
}




public Class B
{
    public int c { get; set; };
}  



public Class Test
{
    A a= new A();
    a.b= ? how to initiate this

    a.b.Add(new B(){c = 13};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try this initializing method

```
       A objA = new A();

        objA.a = 10;

        objA.b = new List<B> { new B { C = 20 }, new B { C = 40 }, new B { C = 50 }, new B { C = 60 } };
```

2.Or try this one

```
     A objA = new A();

        objA.a = 10;           

        List<B> bList = new List<B>();

        bList.Add(new B { C = 20 });
        bList.Add(new B { C = 40 });
        bList.Add(new B { C = 50 });
        bList.Add(new B {C=60});

        objA.b = bList;
```

And modify access specifiers of properties.